# (Swift) when does the Cell init from StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift

well, when i approach the cell in layoutDelegate Method, it makes error.

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ~~~, for: indexPath) as? MyCell {
        cell.configure(label: labels[indexPath.row])
        ...
    }
```

in my opinion, the collectionView's method order is
**sizeForItemAt** -> **cellForItemAt**

but i want to know cell's size in **sizeForItemAt**..
is the cell's init timing **cellForItemAt**???
I want to know cell's init timing..

Comment: Couldn’t you check this really easy by just putting a breakpoint in both methods and seeing which gets called first?

Comment: yes. it's exactly sizeForItemAt -> cellForItemAt
but what i want to know is why cell in sizeForItemAt does not be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know size inside `sizeForItemAt`.

Looks like you already have `configure` method in your cell. You can add constraints inside your cell and modify `constant` value depending on your model:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    func configure(label: String) {
        constraint.constant = // new value
    }
}
```

If you can't do that or prefer working with real frames, the only place you should interact with real view size is your cell `layoutSubviews()`.

Call `setNeedsLayout()` to make sure cell will `layoutSubviews`: on first appearance it'll do it automatically, but when reusing it may not. Something like this:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    func configure(label: String) {
        setNeedsLayout()
        somePrameter = // new value
    }
    private var somePrameter: CGFloat?
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let somePrameter = somePrameter {
            // do your calculations
        }
    }
}
```